# How to create horizontal listview which is fix the count of item when display

Tags: android, listview

I want to create a horizontal listview which contain many item, one item will contain a image. When user slide listview => the count of item will be fix when it display, example display only 3 or 4 image. How can I do that? Many thanks.

**Edit:**

I use [this](http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/34)

to create a HorizontalList view, everything is ok but I don;t know how to make the Next and Previous button work! Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a horizontal ListView (which, as far as I know, isn't offered by the Android SDK) you can use a HorizontalScrollView. You can add the items like to any other kind of layout class.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you are looking for is a Paginated Gallery. I have written one [here](https://github.com/sfarooq/PaginatedGallery).

Its still only a couple of days old but hopefully the included Activity code will get you off the ground.